# How to create user in linux by providing uid and gid options?

Tags: linux

I have 2 linux machines.  On one machine these are the users:

```
sysadmin2:x:4201:4200::/home/sysadmin2:/bin/bash
appadmin1:x:4100:4100::/home/appadmin1:/bin/bash
appadmin2:x:4101:4100::/home/appadmin2:/bin/bash
dataadmin1:x:4300:4300::/home/dataadmin1:/bin/bash
dataadmin2:x:4301:4300::/home/dataadmin2:/bin/bash
sysadmin1:x:4200:4200::/home/sysadmin1:/bin/bash
```

I want to replicate these to another machine.  How can I create these users with same uid and gid values?   Is there a way I can copy them to another machine?

Answer (score 52):

First, create the group if it doesn't exist:

```
$ groupadd -g 4200 sysadmin2
```

Next, create the user and add it to the group:

```
$ useradd sysadmin2 -u 4201 -g 4200 -m -s /bin/bash
$ useradd appadmin1 -u 4100 -g 4100 -m -s /bin/bash
```

and don't forget to reset password for each user.

Comment: also, groups must exist before creating users. `groupadd sysadmin2 -g 4200`

Comment: I have added a new user this way, but it is completely missing from the /etc/group file. Do you know why?

Answer (score 11):

In summary and in general, you can use the `useradd` command to add users to a linux system.  The `-u` flag allows you to set a specific user id and the `-g` flag allows you to set a specific group id.  Please see [`useradd`'s manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) for more details -- on a terminal, type `man useradd` to see it.

Now, specifically about your problem, see below.

Assumming you have three groups on your original machine:

```
$ cat /etc/group
...
appadmins:x:4100:
sysadmins:x:4200:
dataadmins:x:4300:
...
```

On your destination/new machine, you should first create the groups using:

```
groupadd appadmins -g4100
groupadd sysadmins -g4200
groupadd dataadmins -g4300
```

Then, you can proceed to create the actual users like so:

```
useradd appadmin1 -u4100 -g4100 -d/home/appadmin1 -s/bin/bash
useradd appadmin2 -u4101 -g4100 -d/home/appadmin1 -s/bin/bash
useradd sysadmin1 -u4200 -g4200 -d/home/sysadmin1 -s/bin/bash
useradd sysadmin2 -u4201 -g4200 -d/home/sysadmin2 -s/bin/bash
useradd dataadmin1 -u4300 -g4300 -d/home/dataadmin1 -s/bin/bash
useradd dataadmin2 -u4301 -g4300 -d/home/dataadmin2 -s/bin/bash
```

The `-d` option is used to set the home directory and the `-s` option is used to set the shell.  Again, `-u` and `-g` are used to set a specific user and group id.

To check that everything went correctly, just use `grep admin` on your `/etc/passwd` file:

```
$ grep admin /etc/passwd
appadmin1:x:4100:4100::/home/appadmin1:/bin/bash
appadmin2:x:4101:4100::/home/appadmin1:/bin/bash
sysadmin1:x:4200:4200::/home/sysadmin1:/bin/bash
sysadmin2:x:4201:4200::/home/sysadmin2:/bin/bash
dataadmin1:x:4300:4300::/home/dataadmin1:/bin/bash
dataadmin2:x:4301:4300::/home/dataadmin2:/bin/bash
```

If something is wrong, you can use [`userdel`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) or [`groupdel`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/groupdel) accordingly and start over.

Answer (score 0):

The account configure files could be shared by any Linux machine in same privileges. you could make a copy to that machine to have a same user list by this command:

```
scp /etc/{passwd,shadow} root@your_marchine_IP_address:/etc/ -p
```